# Get the domain that is doing the cross domain request in PHP?

Tags: php, cross-domain

I've got a site where I do a cross domain call to my other site. Is there a possibility to see what domain is trying to do the cross domain request?

Let me clarify this with an **example**:

On my site `example.com` I make a cross domain request to `test.com`. In `test.com`, `example.com` is allowed to make a cross domain request. So it will run the code. Now, in that piece of code I'm running, I want to see which site made the request. So in this case I want it to return `example.com`.

Is this possible?

Comment: That’s what the `Origin` header is for ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` should contain that information. According to the php official documentation

> 'HTTP_REFERER' The address of the page (if any) which referred the
>   user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all
>   user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Answer (score -1):

You can include the name of the website, example.com with your cross domain request.